# how to use shutdown call in linux using assembly programming 64-bit?

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit

i made this program as executable but the system is not shutting down.this also needs admin privs.

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
      mov rax,48 ;shutdown system call
      mov rdi,60 ;time taken to shutdown(1 hour)
      syscall
      mov rax,60
      mov rdi,0
      syscall
```

Comment: That is not a system shutdown function. That is a network socket shutdown. See [man 2 shutdown](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html).

Comment: I mistaken it as system shutdown function.Thanks for clarification.I swear i won't repeat this again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shutdown system call does not shut down the system.  It implements the `shutdown()` function which shuts down communication on a socket.  If you want to turn off the system, use the `reboot()` system call.  See [reboot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) for documentation.

However, be advised that calling `reboot` with appropriate arguments immediately turns off the system without giving software time to shut down properly and without synchronising the file systems. I strongly recommend you to instead shut down the system by invoking the `shutdown` utility which does the right thing depending on your init system.  If you don't want to do that, you should at least invoke `sync()` first to commit all in-flight data to disk.

Comment: @RaviTejaParuchuri I don't know any, honestly.